# Click menu and open new window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qmenu

I have used Qt designer to create two different windows, input_window.ui and help_window.ui. Here is the python scripts for showing the input window. In input window, there is a menu bar("About>>Help"). How could it pop up a help_window when "Help" is clicked?

> Here is **init**.py

```
import sys
from input_window import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from help_window import Ui_Help



class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Pophelp.triggered.connect(self.Ui_Help)


    def help_window(self):
        self.window=Ui_Help()
        self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the code of Ui_Help

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Help(object):
    def setupUi(self, Help):
        Help.setObjectName("Help")
        Help.resize(251, 99)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("logo.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Help.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Help)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 231, 81))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(font)
        self.plainTextEdit.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.plainTextEdit.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.plainTextEdit.setLineWidth(1)
        self.plainTextEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Help)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Help)
```

Comment: @PRMoureu, sorry for wrong post in answer section, I have updated the code in my question.

Comment: @PRMoureu, I had seen there is an update, but sorry that I did not see that in detail because there was an issue at that time, could you please show the answer? It seems those answers are deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt Designer serves to implement the view in a simple way, and therefore the class that generates is oriented to the view, and our job is to implement the logic like you did with `Ui_MainWindow` and `MainWindow`, similarly you do with `Ui_Help`. In your case I recommend that when you have built `help_window.ui` you would have used the Dialog template, but if you chose the Widget template there is no problem, both are very compatible.

A simple solution is to create a `QDialog` and implement in it the `Ui_Help` view as shown below:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Pophelp.triggered.connect(self.help_window)

    def help_window(self):
        # If you pass a parent (self) will block the Main Window,
        # and if you do not pass both will be independent,
        # I recommend you try both cases.
        widget = QDialog(self)
        ui=Ui_Help()
        ui.setupUi(widget)
        widget.exec_()
```

If in the `Ui_Help` you want to implement some logic I recommend creating a class similar to `MainWindow` as shown below:

```
class Help(QDialog, Ui_Help):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Help, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Pophelp.triggered.connect(self.help_window)

    def help_window(self):
        widget = Help()
        widget.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include input_window.ui so it's hard to fully replicate what you are doing, but I think the main problem you have is stemming from this line:

```
self.Pophelp.triggered.connect(self.Ui_Help)
```

You don't want to connect the button to Ui_Help, you want to connect it to `self.help_window`.

Comment: thanks for answer, when connect to help_window, it shows an "attribute error: no Ui_Help has no attribute show".

Answer (score 0):

It works if change the help_window to the code below.

```
def help_window(self):
    dialog=QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui=Ui_Help()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
    dialog.show()
```